# Is $\iiint_{[0, 1]^3} \lvert f(x)+f(y)+f(z)\rvert\, dx\, dy\, dz \ge \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert\, dx$?

Tags: inequalities, integration

$\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}\newcommand\Abs[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}$**Question**: Let $f(x)$ be a continuous real-valued function deﬁned on the interval $[0, 1]$. Does the following inequality hold? $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dotsi\int_0^1\int_0^1\abs{f(x_{1})+f(x_{2})+\dotsb+f(x_{n})}dx_1 \; dx_{2}\dotsm\;dx_{n} \ge \int_0^1 \abs{f(x)}dx.$$

Even the case $n=3$ would be interesting. This is inspired by the case $n=2$, which was a Putnam problem from 2003, as follows.

**Theorem**. Let $f(x)$ be a continuous real-valued function deﬁned on the interval $[0, 1]$. Then $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\abs{f(x)+f(y)}dx \; dy \ge \int_0^1 \abs{f(x)}dx.$$

**Proof** by Kent Merryfield:

Let $P$ be the subset of $[0, 1]$ on which $f\ge 0$ and $N$ the set on which $f < 0$. As is conventional, define $f^+(x) = \max(f(x), 0)$ and $f^-(x) = \max(-f(x), 0)$. Thus, $f = f^+ - f^-$, $|f| = f^+ + f^-$, and $f^+$ equals $0$ everywhere on $N$ while $f^-$ equals zero everywhere on $P$.

Then
\begin{align*}\int_0^1 \int_0^1   \abs{f(x) + f(y)}\,dx\,dy &= \int_P  \int_P   \abs{f(x) + f(y)}\,dx,dy +  \int_P  \int_N   \abs{f(x) + f(y)} \,dx\, dy  \\
                &+ \int_N  \int_P   \abs{f(x) + f(y)}\, dx \,dy+ \int_N \int_N   \abs{f(x) + f(y)}\, dx\, dy.\end{align*}
We tackle these terms one at a time.
\begin{align*}\int_P  \int_P   \abs{f(x) + f(y)}\, dx\, dy &=  \int_P  \int_P   (f(x) + f(y))\,dx \,dy\\
        &= \abs P \int_P   f(x)\,dx  + \abs P  \int_P   f(y) \,dy = 2\abs P\int_P   f^+(x) \,dx\end{align*}
where we use the notation $\abs P$ to mean the measure (total net length) of the set $P$.

Similarly, $\int_N \int_N   \abs{f(x) + f(y)} \,dx \,dy = 2\abs N\int_N   f^-(x) \,dx$.

The other two terms are equal to each other (as shown by interchanging $x$ and $y$).
\begin{align*}\int_P \int_N   \abs{f(x) + f(y)} \,dx \,dy &=  \int_P  \int_N   \abs{f^+(x) - f^-(y)} \,dx \,dy\\
&\ge \Abs{\int_P  \int_N   f^+(x) - f^-(y) \,dx \,dy}\\
&=  \Abs{ \abs N\int_P   f^+(x) \,dx -  \abs P\int_N   f^-(y) \,dy}\end{align*}
If we let $A =  \int_P   f^+(x) \,dx$,  $B =  \int_N   f^-(x) \,dx$, and $I = \int_0^1 \int_0^1   \abs{f(x) + f(y)} \,dx \,dy$, then we have found that $I \ge 2\abs P A + 2\abs N B + 2\abs{(\abs N A - \abs P B)}$.

For convenience, we now square this:
\begin{align*}I^2   &\ge 4\left[(\abs P A + \abs N B)^2 + (\abs N A - \abs P B)^2 + (\text{other positive terms})\right]\\
    &\ge 4(\abs P^2A^2 + \abs N^2B^2 + \abs N^2A^2 + \abs P^2B^2)\\
    &= 4(\abs P^2 + \abs N^2)(A^2 + B^2).\end{align*}
But for real $a$ and  $b$, $(a + b)^2 \le 2(a^2 + b^2)$ since $2(a^2 + b^2) - (a + b)^2 = (a - b)^2$.

Hence, $2(\abs P^2 + \abs N^2) \ge (\abs P + \abs N)^2 = 1^2$, since $\abs P + \abs N$ is the measure of the interval $[0, 1]$.
Also, $2(A^2 + B^2) \ge (A + B)^2 =  \left(\int_0^1  \abs{f(x)} \,dx\right)^2$. $\square$

Comment: Here are some preliminary reductions.  Step functions are $L^1$ dense, so we can assume that $f$ is a step function.  Then we can apply a measure-automorphism of $[0,1]$ to ensure that $f$ is weakly increasing.  Then if we want we can do another $L^1$ approximation to reduce to the case where $f$ is strictly increasing and piecewise-linear.  This means that $f=F'$ for some strictly convex $F$, which can be normalised to have $\min(F)=0$.  I don't know if any of that helps.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=a$ on $[0,\frac12]$ and $f(x)=b$ on $(\frac12,1]$. Then the inequality for $n=3$ is $$\frac{|3a|+3|2a+b|+3|a+2b|+|3b|}{8}\ge \frac{|a|+|b|}{2}$$ which reduces to $$3|2a+b|+3|a+2b|\ge|a|+|b|$$That inequality is true, but is there a way to make it obvious?

Comment: I found the reference to "on $[0, 1]$" in the title confusing since there is no free variable.  I did a bit of proofreading in the text, and changed the title so that it did not appear to refer to a free variable but, I think, without otherwise changing its meaning.  I hope that this was all right.

Comment: @MattF. If I understood your question, the result is trivial since $|x+y|\ge|x|-|y|$ it even follows that $3|2a+b|+3|a+2b|\ge 3|a|+3|b|$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the proof using the alternative route.

Let $X$, $Y$ be two independent real-valued random variables such that $EX,EY\ge 0$ and $\min(E|X|,E|Y|)=I$. We want to prove that $E|X+Y|\ge I$. Again, as in both the OP and Iosif's post, we can consider only the case when $X$ is $A$ with probability $P$ and $-B$ with probability $Q$, while $Y$ is $a$ with probability $p$ and $-b$ with probability $q$, where $A,B,a,b\ge 0$.

Then we need to show that the inequality
$$
(A+a)Pp+|a-B|pQ+|b-A|Pq+(B+b)Qq<I
$$
is impossible. So suppose it holds.

If we estimate each absolute value by what is inside it, we get
$$
(A+a)Pp+(a-B)pQ+(b-A)Pq+(B+b)Qq
\\
=(ap+bq)+(AP-BQ)(p-q)
\\=E|Y|+(EX)(p-q)<I\,,
$$
which is possible only if $p<q$.
By symmetry, we conclude that we must also have $P<Q$.

Now estimate $|a-B|\ge a-B$ and $|b-A|\ge A-b$. We obtain
$$
(A+a)Pp+(a-B)pQ+(A-b)Pq+(B+b)Qq
\\
=(AP+ap)+BQ(q-p)+bq(Q-P)<I\,.
$$
However, the last two terms are nonnegative and the condition $0\le EX=AP-BQ$ implies that $AP\ge \frac 12[AP+BQ]=\frac 12E|X|\ge\frac 12I$ and similarly for $ap$, so we run into a contradiction.

*Edit* Here is the direct binomial coefficient approach. I'll start where Iosif stopped though I'll denote by $A$ what he denotes by $A/p$, etc.

We need the inequality
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}p^kq^{n-k}|Ak-B(n-k)|\ge Ap+Bq
$$
Fix $A+B=1$ and consider the difference as a function of $A\in[0,1]$. It is piecewise linear, so the minimum is attained at a zero of some absolute value. Clearly, the endpoints (when the random variable preserves sign) are not competitors, so it is enough to consider the case when $A=\frac{n-\ell}n, B=\frac{\ell}n$, $0<\ell<n$. Then all the absolute values except the vanishing one for $k=\ell$ are at least $A+B=1$, so the LHS is at least
$
1-{n\choose \ell}p^\ell q^{n-\ell}
$
and we want to show that
$$
1-{n\choose \ell}p^\ell q^{n-\ell}\ge Ap+Bq\,,
$$
i.e.,
$$
Aq+Bp\ge {n\choose \ell} p^{\ell}q^{n-\ell}
$$
Since $Aq+Bp\ge q^Ap^B=p^{\frac{\ell}{n}}q^{\frac{n-\ell}{n}}$, it suffices to check that
$$
{n\choose \ell} [p^{\ell}q^{n-\ell}]^{1-\frac 1n}\le 1\,.
$$
The product in brackets is maximized when $p=\frac \ell n$, $q=\frac{n-\ell}{n}$, so we want
$$
{n\choose \ell}[(\tfrac{\ell}n)^{\ell}(\tfrac{n-\ell}n)^{n-\ell}]^{1-\frac 1n}\le 1\,.
$$
Now the LHS can be rewritten as $\frac{n}{\ell^{\frac \ell n}(n-\ell)^{\frac{n-\ell}n}}U$ where
$$
U={n-1\choose \ell-1}(\tfrac{\ell}n)^{\ell-1}(\tfrac{n-\ell}n)^{n-\ell}={n-1\choose \ell}(\tfrac{\ell}n)^{\ell}(\tfrac{n-\ell}n)^{n-\ell-1}
$$
Since $U$ appears as two equal terms in the binomial expansion of
$
[\tfrac{\ell}{n}+\tfrac{n-\ell}n]^{n-1}\,,
$
we must have $U\le \frac 12$. On the other hand, $\frac 1{\alpha^\alpha\beta^\beta}\le 2$ for $\alpha,\beta>0, \alpha+\beta=1$, and we are done again.

It would be interesting to see what factor on the right hand side can be put in place of $1$ for $n\ge 3$. I suspect that the worst case for even $n$ is addition of $n$ Rademacher independent random variables ($\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 12$ each) even if we allow them to be different (but with expectations of the same sign) but I have no proof of it at the moment. The odd case may have a rather ugly answer even for $n=3$.

Comment: If $X$ is centered at the median, the last question is partially answered in item 15 of *Complements and details* to Section 19 of Loéve's book *Probability Theory I*, [DOI:10.1007/978-1-4684-9464-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9464-8). He gives an inequality with an additional factor $\tfrac{(2k+1)!}{(2^kk!)^2}$ if $n=2k+1$ or $n=2k+2$. An example that follows shows that if $X=1$ with probability $\tfrac23$ and $X=-2$ with probability $\tfrac13$, then $E|X+Y+Z|=E|X+Y|=\tfrac43 E|X|$. I do not know right away if these constants are optimal.

Answer (score 14):

A more conveniently written and slightly more general version of the desired result is as follows:
$$E\Big|\sum_{i\in[n]}X_i\Big|\ge E|X_1|,$$
where the $X_i$'s are iid random variables (r.v.'s) with a finite mean.

Let $p:=P(X_i\ge0)$, $q:=1-p$, $A:=EX_i^+$, $B:=EX_i^-$.
Without loss of generality, $0<p<1$.
For $J\subseteq[n]$, let
$$I_J:=1(X_j\ge0\ \forall j\in J,X_j<0\ \forall j\notin J).$$
Following the lines of the first part of the proof for $n=2$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
E\Big|\sum_{i\in[n]}X_i\Big| 
&=\sum_{J\subseteq[n]}E\Big|\sum_{i\in[n]}X_i\Big|\,I_J \\ 
&=\sum_{J\subseteq[n]}E\Big|\sum_{i\in[n]}X_i\,
I_j\Big| \\ 
&=\sum_{J\subseteq[n]}E\Big|\Big(\sum_{i\in J}X_i^+-\sum_{i\notin J}X_i^-\Big)\,
I_J\Big| \\ 
&\ge\sum_{J\subseteq[n]}\Big|E\Big(\sum_{i\in J}X_i^+-\sum_{i\notin J}X_i^-\Big)\,
I_j\Big| \\ 
&=\sum_{J\subseteq[n]}\big||J|A/p-(n-|J|)B/q\big|\,p^{|J|}q^{n-|J|} \\ 
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\big|kA/p-(n-k)B/q\big|\,p^{k}q^{n-k}\binom nk=:s_n(p,A,B). 
\end{aligned}$$
Note also that
$$s_n(p,A,B)=E\big|AX/p-(n-X)B/q\big|,$$
where $X$ is a r.v. with the binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$.

Without loss of generality, $A+B=1$. It remains to show that
$$s_n(p,A,1-A)\ge1$$
for all $A\in[0,1]$. Graphing suggests this is true.

Unfortunately, the second, "squaring" part of the proof for $n=2$ will not work even for $n=3$ and $p$ close enough to $1/2$; that is, the inequality
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\Big(\big(kA/p-(n-k)B/q\big)\,p^{k}q^{n-k}\binom nk\Big)^2\ge(A+B)^2$$
will not hold for such $n,p$.

Comment: You are overthinking it a bit. :-) Indeed, you can immediately reduce the problem to a 2-value case as you did. But you don't need to square anything to check the resulting inequality. An alternative (if you do not want to bother with binomial coefficients) is to generalize the statement to $E|X+Y|\ge \min(E|X|,E|Y|)$ when $EX$ and $EY$ have the same sign, prove that, and induct. I have to teach now. I'll post later unless somebody beats me to it.

Comment: @fedja : Your inequality for $X$ and $Y$ is very nice!

Comment: Thanks,so for my question when $n=3$ not hold for any $f?$

Comment: @inequality It surely does. Moreover, we can get a better constant factor than $1$ on the RHS though to find the best one may be quite a headache.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I added to my answer the endgame for your approach (and an additional question). Enjoy!

Comment: @fedja : That is another great answer of yours! I think your inequality for $X$ and $Y$ needs to be widely known -- so, perhaps you can consider publishing it.