# is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{i}+a_{j}|\cdot p_{i}p_{j}\ge \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}|a_{i}|$?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, inequalities

see:[old post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383174/is-iiint-0-13-lvert-fxfyfz-rvert-dx-dy-dz-ge-int-01-l?noredirect=1#comment974849_383174)
and Make the integral discrete, we have

conjecture  :for any complex numbers $a_{i},i=1,2,\cdots,n$,and $p_{i}\ge 0$ such $p_{1}+p_{2}+\cdots+p_{n}=1$,then maybe be have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{i}+a_{j}|\cdot p_{i}p_{j}\ge \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}|a_{i}|$$

How prove this complex inequality?Thanks

take $p_{i}=\dfrac{1}{n},i=1,2,\cdots,n$,and Amuess that $a_{i}\in R$.I have prove that following

**Theorem **.$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{i}+a_{j}|\ge n\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}|$$
proof: Equality occurs if all $x_k$ are null, or else if $n$ is even, half the variables are equal to any real number $a$, and the other half are equal to $-a$. The proof goes along the lines exposed in the above, but an alternate solution, given by C. Tanasescu, is worth mentioning.

Use the obvious equality $|a| + |b| - |a+b| = 0$ if $ab\geq 0$ and $= 2\min\{|a|,|b|\}$ if $ab<0$.
Then $$\begin{align*}\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n} (|x_i| + |x_j| - |x_i+x_j|) &= \sum_{x_ix_j< 0} 2\min\{|x_i|,|x_j|\}\\
& = 4\sum_{x_i>0>x_j}\min\{x_i,-x_j\} \leq 4\sum_{x_i>0>x_j}\sqrt{-x_ix_j} \\
&= 4\sum_{x_i>0}\sqrt{x_i} \sum_{0>x_j}\sqrt{-x_j} \leq \left (\sum_{x_i>0}\sqrt{x_i} + \sum_{0>x_j}\sqrt{-x_j}\right )^2 \\
&=\left (\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\sqrt{|x_k|}\right )^2 \\
&\leq n\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_k|\end{align*}$$

It follows $\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n} |x_i+x_j| + n\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_k| \geq \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n} (|x_i| + |x_j|) = 2n\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}|x_k|$, which is equivalent to the required inequality

Comment: Suppose each $p_i$ is of the form $n_i/q$. Then define $b_i$’s where each $a_i$ is replicated $n_i$ times. If you write out theorem 2 for the $b_i$’s and divide through by $q^2$, you obtain conjecture 1 in the case where all $p_i$ are rational. Now take limits.

Comment: All your conjectures here have been settled in the "old post" thread, so I see no reason to open a new one. Besides, it is fairly well known that $4=2\times 2$, so the $2$ function inequality immediately implies the $4$ function one...

Comment: @fedja: Maybe this post was edited, but I think the point of the new question is that the variables are now complex numbers.

Comment: @GHfromMO Come on! Just project and average, that's it :-)

Comment: @fedja: So the inequality also works in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (hence also in any Hilbert space), right?

Comment: @GHfromMO Yes, of course. Now, if you want values in an *arbitrary Banach space*, it gets trickier and I'm not sure anymore, but that is certainly not what the OP asked. Want to open a separate thread for that? I'm afraid that there may be trivial counterexamples though.

Comment: @fedja: I don't want a separate thread, at least not now. I am happy with Hilbert spaces for the time being :-)